# How to handle Pika consumers on multi processing system

Tags: python, concurrency, rabbitmq, pika

I have a multi-process and multi-thread system which works with Pika to consume some queues.
When system works on a single-process with multi-thread consumers, it works fine but when it works with multi-process (spawned processes), some times some consumers fetch a duplicate data from queue.

How to handle this issue that when a consumer fetch a data from a queue, other consumers never fetch that data from that queue again?

Sample map from issue:

```
Single-Process, Multi-Thread:
    Sample queue data: 1-2-3-4-5
        consumed by thread-1: 5
        consumed by thread-2: 4
        ...

Multi-Process, Multi-Thread:
    Sample queue data: 1-2-3-4-5
        consumed by process-1, thread-1: 5   << ISSUE
        consumed by process-2, thread-1: 4
        consumed by process-3, thread-3: 5   << ISSUE
        ...
```

**Note:** each thread has its own connection.

Comment: RabbitMQ would never serve the same data twice, unless you consume the message and reject it and re-queue it. This is either a bug in pika or your application. Would be difficult to troubleshoot without more details about your implementation.

Comment: Do you create your Pika client before creating additional processes or threads? The Pika client is neither thread-safe nor multi-process safe as noted in [the docs](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.11.0/faq.html). Without providing a working example I can't diagnose this particular behavior further.